# On default.aspx, how can I properly control the Ribbon with OOB webparts?

Tags: 2010, ribbon, data-form-web-part

In a team site, I have put two DataFormWebPart (in new mode) that allow users to directly push data to two SP lists.

The two webpart are saving data as expected, but the ribbon is weird when having these webparts.

What I expected :

- if focus is in the 1st webpart, show the ribbon for the new form of the first list i.e. show the "Item" tab of the ribbon.
- if focus is in the 2nd webpart, show the ribbon for the new form of the second list i.e. show the "Item" tab of the ribbon.
- if focus is elsewhere, show the ribbon accordingly

What I get :

As soon as I have one of this webpart, the ribbon directly goes to the "Edit" tab, which correspond to the first inserted web part. If I focus the second webpart, the ribbon isn't updated. If I focus another webpart, the ribbon add the correct tabs.

How can I propertly setup multiple DataFormWebPart on the home page of a site ?

Comment: I don't think this is a supported scenario, having two dataform insert webparts on the same page. I've never seen a duplicate Item tab the way you describe it, and due to ID's being doubled I don't think it's possible at all. 

Why not use two seperate pages, or create a custom webpart which writes to both lists at once? If you want to provide insert functionality on two things, you could also go with two links opening modal popups with the insert forms on them, that way your users can stay on the same page.

Comment: How frustrated I am when I see how Microsoft has build their webcontrols. It's so hard (sometimes nearly impossible) to reuse some basic blocks. Simple things are getting very complicated compared to a custom web apps :'(

Answer (score 1):

It works fine in my case. I added two different list data views to a page from the SP2010 designer and the ribbon works as expected.

May be you should use XsltListViewWebPart and not DataFormWebPart.

Comment: please, show us code of how you inserted this webpart

Comment: Amit, showing lists is easy. What I was not able to do is to use *input* webparts (having ControlMode set to NewForm)

Comment: @Amit, i'd like to see the code for that.